# How can I properly call the erf function from scipy.special?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to use the erf function with python and I come across the error:

```
  File "java.py", line 40, in <module>
    getQ(x) 
  File "java.py", line 13, in getQ
    q = math.log(1.0- erf.erf(math.abs(x)/SQRT2))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ufunc' object has no attribute 'erf'
```

This is my code:

```
import math 
from scipy.special import erf 

SQRT2 = math.sqrt(2.0)
x=2
ERRMUL = 1.0

def getQ(x): 
    q = math.log(1.0-erf.erf(math.abs(x)/SQRT2))
    print q
getQ(x)
```

Is there a specific module I'm supposed to be implementing?

Comment: what do you expect `erf.erf` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call [`erf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erf.html), not `erf.erf` (which doesn't exist and thus raises the Exception) and it's just `abs` not `math.abs`:

```
def getQ(x): 
    q = math.log(1.0-erf(abs(x)/SQRT2))
    print(q)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to convert it from some java code which had erf.erf
I wasn't sure about that either.